# Hide of tabbar shows whitespace (even if frame is fullscreen)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, whitespace, uitabbar

Trying to make fullscreen view in a tabbarcontroller. It's in landscape. Are able to hide the tabbar with `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES` this leaves a whitespace where the tabbar have been.

Making the tabbarcontroller's view fullscreen with:

```
self.tabBarController.view.frame = self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
[self.tabBarController.view setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f)];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
self.tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Then I try to make the viewcontrollers view fullscreen also. But it will not stick, unable to resize `view.frame`.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
[self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f)];
```

Is there anyway to get around this in a nice fashion?!

[Image of whitespace (in red) were tabbar is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgfBr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property to YES before pushing your viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with autoresizingMask property of your view controllers instead of trying to resize manually the view frames ?

```
self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
self.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same whitespace (59px) below viewcontrollers view. Almost the same as included picture.